# How to read a decimal in libxml2?

Tags: c, libxml2

I have an xml file in below format and I decided to use libxml2 after experts suggested I go for this in this forum. I started with little knowledge.

```
<ACCOUNT NO="123>
   <STATE> FL </STATE>
   <PERCENT>10.2</PERCENT>
</ACCOUNT>
```

Now my question is , since value of PERCENT tag is floating, how do I read PERCENT tag value in C?
EDIT: I knew we have C function to convert it from string. My question is do we have any in-built functions in libxml2 that supports?

Comment: A much bigger problem is that the XML is invalid (not well-formed).

Comment: I just gave an example to show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libxml gives you a string which you can convert to an int or float using whatever method you wish... in C strtol or strtod, using a stringstream in c++, etc etc...

Comment: Right , my question is do we any in-build data types in the libxml for int/float?

Comment: Not that i know of; there wouldn't be much of a point since your platform already provides that, just convert the string :)

Comment: Hmm then I flag to delete this post. Please vote to close this post.

Answer (score 1):

Read it in as a string, and then use [`strtod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to convert it to a `double`.